# Collapsing tabs in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a tabbed menu using bootstrap. And my code is like this,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle red" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Menu" id="menuButton">
            <span class="sr-only red">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar red"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar red"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar red"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myNavbar">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

For some reason, the stacked three bars are being invisible in the top right corner of the page when I re-size the window. If I click on that invisible white space, the menu is expanding and collapsing if I click again.

What am I missing here?

My sample code [here](http://jsbin.com/diqojehoba/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navbar-toggle icon-bar` background-color is not set. You have to manually set the `background-color` to red in your style sheet i.e

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
    background-color:red;
}
```

or you can use inline css i.e

```
<span class="icon-bar red" style="background-color:red"></span>
```

Comment: Can you also let me know how to center the button tag during resizing?

Comment: You can use `media-queries` and `flex-box`